# VB.NET Keep adding values in a label

Tags: vb.net, label

I'm doing a scoreboard using labels for scores, but the number doesn't keep on adding, it only add once. what could be the problem?

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As Integer
    a = a + 1

    Label1.Text = a

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Move `Dim a As Integer` out of the `Button1_Click` sub, otherwise you are declaring a new one every time you click the button - which is the reason to why it always stays the same.

Comment: thanks for the info and answer sir!

Comment: Can also change it to a static inside your sub: Static a As Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `a` is local to the button_click event. So every time you call this event clicking your button the variable is allocated on the stack and has its initial value set to the default for integer which is zero

If you want to keep a counter you need to declare the variable at the global level where its scope *is the set of all code in your form*

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim a As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         a = a + 1    
         Label1.Text = a
     End Sub
End Class
```

More details on lifetime and scope of variables could be read in this MSDN article: [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) and [Lifetime, Scope, Visibility, and Linkage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/592xa3sk.aspx). Read it carefully because a deep understanding of these issues is fundamental to learn programming.

Comment: I think he wants to add to it every time he presses the button, so you should probably move `a = a + 1` into the click event.

Comment: Could also use a += 1